# how does gcc deal with defines that use operators on other defines

Tags: gcc, compilation

If I have the follow snippet in my header file:

```
#define banana 4
#define orange 2

#define fruit banana|orange
```

Is the compiler smart enough to just use 6 wherever "fruit" appears in the program?

I assume so, but I hate to assume.  It's idiotic that it would perform a boolean OR between 2 constant numbers every time.

If so, ditto with other operators? e.g. banana * orange, etc

Comment: You REALLY need to surround the or'd values with parens, like `(banana!orange)`, otherwise you will find yourself pulling out hair when you use `fruit` in any kind of expression involving an operator of higher precedence (which is most of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define` lines are directives to perform text substitution.  This is a separate phase of the compilation, called preprocessing. The name should hint you that it happens before normal processing.

The compiler textually replaces `#define`d names with their definitions at the very early stage. In your example, it replaces `banana` with `2`, `orange` with `4`, `fruit` with `banana|orange` and then with `2|4`. For the rest of the compilation it only sees `2|4`, and deals with it exactly like with any other constant expression.

Are compiles smart enough to deal with constant expressions intelligently? Well, the compilers are around for the last 50 years, and they deal with constant expressions like this all this time. Be rest assured they know about [constant folding](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) quite a bit. If you doubt it, you can always look at the generated assembly language.

Comment: Right but does the compiler ultimately use 2|4 or 6?  Like if I have code that says int food = fruit (or even just food = 2|4), will the instructions generated be a simple mov ..., 6 or at least 2 instructions (one to load 2, 2nd to OR it with 4)?

Comment: Have you tried to read what I wrote, or perhaps follow the link and read that Wikipedia article?

Comment: Of course I read what you wrote and frankly, it didn't tell me anything I didn't know already, up until the bit about constant folding.  The latter being what I was looking for but I didn't click the link (my bad).  Having done so now, its exactly the info I was after:)